# Using LINQ + XML to scrape website

Tags: c#, html, xml, linq

I am trying to learn .NET technologies and C# by creating a simple scraper that should retrieve some geographic data from Wikipedia.

First, I created this method that from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population) Wikipedia site returns all links to the countries in the table:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetLinkToAllCountries()
{

    return from node in XElement.Load(_URL.AbsoluteUri).Elements("body").Descendants()
           where node.Name.LocalName == "a"
                            && node.Parent.Name.LocalName == "td"
                            && node.Parent.Parent.Name.LocalName == "tr"
                            && node.Attribute("href") != null
                            && node.Attribute("title") != null
                                select _URL.Scheme + "//" + _URL.Host + node.Attribute("href").Value;

}
```

This works fine and returns a list of links to every country's Wiki page. Secondly, I want to visit each country's page and retrieve the capital.

I wrote something similar, but I can't get it to work:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ListOfCapitals() {

    var links = GetLinkToAllCountries();

    return from link in links
           from node in XElement.Load(link).Elements("body").Descendants()
           where node.Name.LocalName == "a"
                && node.Parent.Name == "td"
                && node.Attribute("title") != null
           select node.Attribute("title").Value;
}
```

It doesn't list the capitals, and Visual Studio seems to make some assembly pointers to System.Threading. Should I perhaps write something asynchronous due to the work load (visiting ~200 websites and retrieving data from each)? I would also love some general feedback on the approach if that is not violating any rules in here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way best way to do this is through TPL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

Refactored - Given the following class:

```
public class WebScraper
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetLinkToAllCountries(Uri uri)
    {
        return from node in XElement.Load(uri.AbsoluteUri).Elements("body").Descendants()
            where node.Name.LocalName == "a"
                  && node.Parent.Name.LocalName == "td"
                  && node.Parent.Parent.Name.LocalName == "tr"
                  && node.Attribute("href") != null
                  && node.Attribute("title") != null
            select uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host + node.Attribute("href").Value;

    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ListOfCapitals(string link)
    {
        return from node in XElement.Load(link).Elements("body").Descendants()
            where node.Name.LocalName == "a"
                  && node.Parent.Name == "td"
                  && node.Attribute("title") != null
            select node.Attribute("title").Value;
    }
}
```

You can then have something like the following:

```
        var webScraper = new WebScraper();

        var countryLinks =
            webScraper.GetLinkToAllCountries(
                new Uri("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population"));
        
        var capitals = countryLinks
            .AsParallel()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75)))
            .SelectMany(s => webScraper.ListOfCapitals(s))
            .ToList();
```

`WithDegreeOfParallelism` - how many concurrently executing tasks that will be used to process the query.

Also something to consider is the dependency you have with `XElement.Load(uri.AbsoluteUri)` in `GetLinkToAllCountries` and `XElement.Load(link)` in `ListOfCapitals`.  I'd refactor this so that there is a layer of abstraction - that way the linq queries could be unit tested with mocks.

Comment: Uh, very cool. Need to dig more into all those nifty parallel and other asynchronous calls. Can you elaborate on the part where you use ceciling of the amount of processors times some factors?

I will try your solution out tomorrow!